# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I am trying to submit (Spring) form query:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6BgiW7Q.png]

I don't get the message.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "beerbean", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("beerbean") BeerBean beerbean){
    return "addbeerform";
}



@RequestMapping(value = "beerbean", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newBeer(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute BeerBean beerbean,
        BindingResult bindingResult){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "addbeerform";
    }
    model.addAttribute("beani", beerbean);
    return "showBeer";
}
```

addbeerform.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<form:form commandName="beerbean" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app
     /beerbean" method="POST">

     <form:input path="name" /><form:errors path="name" /><br/>
     <form:input path="id" /><form:errors path="id" /><br/>

     <input type="submit">
</form:form>
```

When there isn't errors in fields it works and goes to "showBeer", but when there is it just crashes. I have also BeerBean class which implements Serializable etc., but don't think the solution is there (variables there are written like parameters in form, input path="name" goes to private String name etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to explicitly specify name of model attribute:

```
public String newBeer(
    Model model,
    @Valid @ModelAttribute("beerbean") BeerBean beerbean,
    BindingResult bindingResult
) {
```